# Duplicate Insert Issue with Hibernate OneToMany relationship in Wildfly

Tags: transactions, duplicates, nhibernate-mapping, record, wildfly

I am having OneToMany Relationship between Timesheet and activity. When I save the timesheet, it insert new Activity twice.

Here is the mapping -

```
@JoinColumn(name = "timesheetId")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Where(clause = "active = 1")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private List<Activity> activities;
```

and in Activity Entity -

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private TimeSheet timesheet;
```

Following are the logs of Merge method of hibernate- it calls insert statement twice of single activity.

I am using Wildfly 8 and Hibernate 4.3.5. I have a doubt if it not because of entity manager? any help will be appreciate.

> 18:11:38,455 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-28) default task-28:[transaction scoped EntityManager]: reuse entity manager session already in tx TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a05a293:604cc77a:54f72b23:213 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
>
> 18:11:38,460 INFO  [stdout] (default task-28) Hibernate: select activityty0_.id as id1_1_0_, activityty0_.active as active2_1_0_, activityty0_.createdById as created17_1_0_, activityty0_.createdDate as createdD3_1_0_, activityty0_.description as descript4_1_0_, activityty0_.modifiedById as modifie18_1_0_, activityty0_.modifiedDate as modified5_1_0_, activityty0_.name as name6_1_0_, activityty0_.allocationGroupCd as allocat19_1_0_, activityty0_.allocationTypeCd as allocat20_1_0_, activityty0_.billable as billable7_1_0_, activityty0_.commentRequiredIndicator as commentR8_1_0_, activityty0_.dayDropable as dayDropa9_1_0_, activityty0_.futureDropable as futureD10_1_0_, activityty0_.headDropable as headDro11_1_0_, activityty0_.holidayDropable as holiday12_1_0_, activityty0_.maximumRequiredTime as maximum13_1_0_, activityty0_.minimumRequiredTime as minimum14_1_0_, activityty0_.standardCode as standar15_1_0_, activityty0_.weekendDropable as weekend16_1_0_ from ActivityType activityty0_ where activityty0_.id=?
>
> 18:11:38,468 INFO  [stdout] (default task-28) Hibernate: select allocation0_.id as id1_2_0_, allocation0_.active as active2_2_0_, allocation0_.createdById as createdB8_2_0_, allocation0_.createdDate as createdD3_2_0_, allocation0_.description as descript4_2_0_, allocation0_.modifiedById as modified9_2_0_, allocation0_.modifiedDate as modified5_2_0_, allocation0_.name as name6_2_0_, allocation0_.standardCode as standard7_2_0_ from AllocationGroup allocation0_ where allocation0_.id=?
>
> 18:11:38,473 INFO  [stdout] (default task-28) Hibernate: select allocation0_.id as id1_3_0_, allocation0_.active as active2_3_0_, allocation0_.createdById as createdB8_3_0_, allocation0_.createdDate as createdD3_3_0_, allocation0_.description as descript4_3_0_, allocation0_.modifiedById as modified9_3_0_, allocation0_.modifiedDate as modified5_3_0_, allocation0_.name as name6_3_0_, allocation0_.standardCode as standard7_3_0_ from AllocationType allocation0_ where allocation0_.id=?
>
> 18:11:38,480 INFO  [stdout] (default task-28) Hibernate: **insert into Activity (active, createdById, createdDate, description, modifiedById, modifiedDate, name, activityTypeId, actual, applicationId, assignmentId, businessAreaId, comment, endDate, etc, startDate, timesheetId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**
>
> 18:11:38,493 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-28) created new TransactionScopedEntityManager for unit name=******.ear/*******-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#*******EM
>   18:11:38,495 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-28) default task-28:[transaction scoped EntityManager]: reuse entity manager session already in tx TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a05a293:604cc77a:54f72b23:213 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
>   18:11:38,497 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-28) default task-28:[transaction scoped EntityManager]: reuse entity manager session already in tx TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a05a293:604cc77a:54f72b23:213 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
>   18:11:38,498 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (default task-28) default task-28:[transaction scoped EntityManager]: reuse entity manager session already in tx TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a05a293:604cc77a:54f72b23:213 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >
>
> 18:11:38,600 INFO  [stdout] (default task-28) Hibernate: **insert into Activity (active, createdById, createdDate, description, modifiedById, modifiedDate, name, activityTypeId, actual, applicationId, assignmentId, businessAreaId, comment, endDate, etc, startDate, timesheetId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**

Comment: Please show the code you use to assemble the data structure and add it to the persistence context. Note that typically you're safer using a Set rather than a List for these relationships. Also ensure that your equals/hashCode implementations are correct (and based on business keys rather than primary keys)

Answer (score 0):

In Wildfly 8 or Hibernate 3.6  and above , If you face this issue, make a thumb rule to do flush before merge.

em.flush();
o = em.merge(o);

That's how I able to resolve this issue.